# How to code into Mathematica

Tags: plotting

Section 10.3: r = 1 + (cos(theta))^999
a.)  Graph the given polar curve. Choose a parameter interval to make sure that you produce the entire curve. (This is called the Pac-Man Curve.)

My code:

```
f[x_] = 1 + Cos[x]^999;
Plot [f[x], {x, -pi, 2 pi}]
```

Comment: What does "Section 10.3" have to do with anything?  A polar curve is in TWO dimensions... see?

Comment: `pi` should be capitalized; that is `Pi`.

Answer (score 2):

```
PolarPlot[1 + Cos[θ]^999,
 {θ, 0, 10}]
```

[image]